# Empty byte arrays passed to Xml Web service call - .asmx, asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, asmx

I have a C# Xml Web service application ( .asmx ). It is a .Net 3.5 C# asp.net application.

One of the Web Methods takes a parameter which is an array of byte arrays ( byte[][] ).

This application is in regular use and works well - the arrays are passed as base 64 coded strings in Xml soap calls.

For a specific set of four bytes arrays, I am finding that the first array is passed OK, but the next 3 arrays are passed with zero length.

It only happens for this specific data - for other data values, with 4 or more arrays of similar size or bigger, the data is always passed correctly.

The 4 arrays are byte data which represent four small .pdf files. The data is from a confidential application so I cannot post it here. They range in size up to 8K, they are not too big for the Web Service configuration.

It seems to happen when the first byte array is length 7168 exactly - ie 7 * 1024 bytes long.

I have checked the soap messages passed over the wire and it contains the correct data for the four byte arrays - so the problem appears to be at the receiving end ( asp.net xml web service ).

Does anyone have similar experience of simliar problems passing byte arrays in Xml web services, thanks, Aengus.

UPDATE: I think it is a bug in WSE 3

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/472448/wse-3-data-corruption